# algebraic number with explicit base two digits

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

I am looking for an irrational algebraic number $\alpha \in [0,1[$ whose base two expansion
$$
\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^\infty {1 \over 2^{\varphi(i)}}, 
$$
is easily computable. By this I mean $\varphi : {\bf N} \rightarrow {\bf N}$ should be strictly increasing and given by an explicit formula involving elementary functions, polynomials, logarithms, square roots, integer parts $\left \lfloor{...}\right \rfloor$  etc.

Roth's theorem tells us that $\varphi(n) = n^2$ does not work.
What about $\lfloor n^{3\over 2} \rfloor$? $\lfloor n+\sqrt{n} \rfloor$? Do they define irrational algebraic numbers?

Comment: It is conjectured that all algebraic irrationals are absolutely normal, in particular normal in base $2$. This would imply that any $\alpha$ of the form you propose in which $\varphi(i)$ grows faster than $2i$ will be irrational. I don't think any algebraic irrationals are expected to have such tidy expansions.

Comment: @Wojowu can you explain "this would imply"? I don't see how it follows from the first thing you said.

Comment: @mathworker21 Let $d(n)$ be the number of $1$s in the expansion of $\alpha$ up to the $n$-th bit. Then normality is equivalent to $d(n)\sim n/2$. If $\varphi(n)$ grows too fast, say $\varphi(n)\geq Cn$ for $C>2$, then this would imply that $d(n)$ is asymptotically at most $n/C$.

Comment: coudy, I'm assuming you also meant for there to be some "easily computable" condition on $a_i$ as well (as otherwise any number in $[0,1]$, rational or not, can be written like that for $\phi(i)=i$. If by a chance you meant all $a_i$ to be equal to $1$, then normality gives an even tigher constraint $\phi(i)\sim 2i$.

Comment: @Wojowu I'm still confused. Can you reread your initial comment? Is the end of the second sentence supposed to be "rational" instead of "irrational"?

Comment: @wojowu indeed this is a typo. There is no need of the $a_i$.

Comment: @Wojowu So I was a bit optimistic. On the other hand, there are normal numbers with tidy digits, such as the champernowne constant -- which is unfortunately a transcendental number.

Comment: You probably won't find what you want, but $\sum t^{2^i} \in \mathbb{F}_2((t))$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_2(t)$. Free yourself from the tyranny of the real numbers :-)